# geofence didEnterRegion not works propertly

Tags: objective-c, ios7, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I try to test geofencing in iOS 7, but dont works propertly.

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/rCg5xUyT

The problem are when I add a CLCircularRegion (radius: 100m) to CLLocationManager, I show UIAlertView when didEnterRegion, but the UIAlertView shows on 1950m, I dont understand why.

I test on simulator, using Debug > Location > Freeway drive
I test too on my iPhone 5, but don't works propertly, the UIAlertView shows when distance from my current location are more than 1950m.

Somebody can help me please ?
Thanks.